# Formulate/code Hermite Interpolation through four points

Tags: c++, interpolation, hermite

Searching for C/C++ implementation of Hermite Interpolation. Please suggest simple/readable/academic program.

Inputs: x and y arrays of doubles with 4 values each. Representing 4 2d points. Please note I do not have tangents with me.

Output: Now given any new value of x (within range of given x values), need to find new y. Please note I do not have parameter 't' with me.

Please suggest formulation and show C/C++ implementation.

Comment: I think [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline) is a good reference (via Google).

Comment: Google "Catmull-Rom spline", which is a type of cubic Hermite interpolation where tangents are inferred from points.